# iTunes Connect - total installs vs current devices that have the app installed

Tags: ios, statistics, app-store-connect

How can I know or calculate an iOS app's total installs vs current devices that have the app installed?

I have the totals units and as I understand that is the total install count and not how many devices have my app right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get more details about app statistics by using 3rd party frameworks such as [Flurry](http://www.flurry.com/). You won't be able to detect if a user uninstalls the app, but you can see how many unique users are using the app in a specific interval. You can also see which OS version your users have installed.

Answer (score 0):

use TestFlight Live for analytics and crash reports for App Store submitted app