# How many installs does my iOS app have?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect

How can I find out how many instances of my app are installed in iOS? On Android I simply go to statistics and they tell me. The number is not exact, but it's generally accurate. On iTunes Connect, I am not sure where to find how many devices/people have my app installed.

I launched the app two days ago, in case that matters.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Press the Sales and Trends button.

[image]

Comment: It's updated once a day. All downloads today will appear tomorrow.

Comment: Welcome! Good luck with the app.

Comment: I think the **Sales and Trends** panel gives you the number of downloads, not the current number of installs. The 2 values can be different.

Comment: More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20996087/itunes-connect-total-installs-vs-current-devices-that-has-the-app-install